# Changing the color or shape of the loader

Tags: autodesk-forge

I am wondering if there is any way to change the loader or the color of the current loader in Forge Viewer? I am referring to the loader that plays when a model is being loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As with similar special customization requests, this is not something that's officially configurable, but since the color is simply defined using CSS, you can override the CSS class called `progressfg`, for example:

```css
.adsk-viewing-viewer .progressfg {
    background: chocolate;
}
```